Using the "tab distance" feature in QGIS labels
I want to define the distance between two fields in a label. It seems like "Tab distance" would be helpful for this but I don't know how to call the tab value in the label.
Screenshot of QGIS labeling settings:


You Just need to insert a tab rather than a space between your two field.
So rather than "name"||' '||"name:en" use "name"||'  '||"name:en" (to insert the tab you need to use the expression builder, just typing a tab in the value field will go to the next item...)

Great, thank you! This works great, except when "Label Placement" is set to "Using Perimeter (curved)" (polygons) or "Curved" (lines). In those cases the "Tab distance" value gets ignored and a standard tab distance is applied.
